Why is it that when I install an update to Git, it refuses to allow me to select VS Code as my default editor?
The last couple of times that I've upgraded Git on my Windows 11 machine, the Git installer refuses to allow me to select Visual Studio Code as my default editor for Git:

Why won't it allow me to use VS Code? I've never encountered this problem before. The Git installer always allowed me to select the editor I wanted to use, so I don't understand why it is preventing me from choosing the editor I want to use.

this is not git strictly speaking, it seems to be a "gitforwindows" installer. You should probably ask that project.

Be advised 2.47.0 is buggy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79078235/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/79094424/7976758

Please ensure that VSCode is setup in your Path variable.. it might not be able to recognize it. Or you can manually setup using commandline :  git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
